# Chrome frontend dev tools - Remote debugging - How to access frontend dev tools urls from web application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have started Google Chrome with remote debugging enabled on port number eg: `9222` and remote allow origins set to `*`.

Using these flags I have open Google Chrome in kiosk mode with enabled remote debugging: `google-chrome --kiosk --disable-infobars --remote-debugging-port=9222 --remote-allow-origins=* http://localhost:8000`.

When I open `http://localhost:9222/json` in browser I get next response:

```
[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/606A9C40AA0DE1CAB7F0167AD384E4DD",
   "id": "606A9C40AA0DE1CAB7F0167AD384E4DD",
   "title": "Web App Title",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "http://localhost:8000",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/606A9C40AA0DE1CAB7F0167AD384E4DD"
} ]
```

In my app I have tried following:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9222/json').then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

but I got CORS error.

Is there any way to bypass CORS or is there any flag to start Chrome without CORS restriction?

My app is running at localhost in `dev` environment on port `8000`.

Comment: If you examine the response in devtools you'll see it doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. It's either a bug in devtools or an intended feature to avoid web sites hijacking into localhost. You can add `--disable-web-security` but it's a big hammer.

Comment: Still no luck, even if I add `--disable-web-security` flag